# Should I compress large pipeline artifacts in azure-devops by myself?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline which publishes large artifact - folder with files of size ~ 500 MB. Currently I compress it before publishing.

Is manual compression step required? I mean that may be there is internal compression mechanism under the hood?

Comment: You compress it yourself ? AzureDevOps has a task called "ArchiveFiles" to compress stuff for you, why not use that ?

Comment: I'm using ArchiveFiles. My question is about need of explicit compression (by any means) being part of pipeline.

Comment: Depends on your artifact and what you do with it later. You do not explicitly need it (and don't have to worry about storage-capacity) but i'd use it anyway. uploading/downloading a folder as an archive is much faster than a folder and its subitems in my experience. But that depends on the kind of artifact you have

Comment: Later I download the artifact from another pipeline and decompress it. 

My question also was inspired by reading "Universal Packages can be huge (we’ve tested up to 4TB), and our deduplication and compression technology can dramatically improve efficiency." from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/getting-started-with-universal-packages/.

But universal packages do not seem useful for me - they require versioning and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> Is manual compression step required?

No, of course not.

A better question is, "Under what circumstances should I compress artifacts?"

The answer to *that* question is: If you're going to be doing network transfers of a lot of little files **and** you're finding the transfer speed to be too slow. If it's not too slow, don't bother compressing. If you have a relatively small number of larger files, don't bother.